# JSON Reads Writes for List[(Foo, List[FoodChildren]) ]

Tags: scala, playframework

As question says

How to best write `Writes [List[(Foo, List[FoodChildren]) ] ]` where each `Foo` and `FoodChildren` itself are `case class` ?

I am on Scala 2.11, play framework 2.3.1

Comment: `List[Foo,List[FooChildren]` isn't valid scala.

- ] missing
- List does not take 2 type parameter

Comment: @planetenkiller : that was simply a typo. corrected now. it's a List of tuples as you can see now

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a third case class instead of a tuple? JSON doesn't support tuples.

If you use a third case class than you can use `Json.format[...]` to build the Reads/Writes.

Comment: Agreed.  Tuples are hard to generalize when it comes to JSON transformation, there's no natural analog in JSON for that structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your own Writer instead of using the macro:

```
implicit val myTupleWrites = new Writes[(Int,List[FoodChildren])] {
  def writes(myTuple: (Int,List[FoodChildren])) = Json.obj(
    "i" -> myTuple._1,
    "lst" -> myTuple._2
  )
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson